# Removing a filter added by a Class from a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin that is running on all post and pages and I want to remove it from the content on a custom template I created for *Thank you* pages.

I printed out all the filters that are added to the content and the one I want to reference is as follows

```
[18de263ad73c07944f622a52d10d6e0ewpsocialite_filter_content] => Array
            (
                [function] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => wpsocialite Object
                            (
                                [options:private] => 
                            )

                        [1] => wpsocialite_filter_content
                    )

                [accepted_args] => 1
            )

    )
```

I have tried many diffrent companations but can't get it right. I would like the final code in my functions.php to look like this

```
<?php if(is_page_template(thank-you.php)){
   remove_filter('the_content', 'wpsocialite_filter_content');
}
```

The main problem is that the filter is being added by Class Object. Here is the code adding it

```
if (!class_exists("wpsocialite")) {

class wpsocialite {
    public static $instance;
    private $options;

    public function WPSocialite() {
        $this->__construct();
    }

    function __construct() {
        self::$instance = $this;

        add_action(     'init',                     array( $this, 'init'                            ) );
        add_action(     'wp_footer',                array( $this, 'wpsocialite_localize_script'     ), 20);

        add_action(     'admin_init',               array( $this, 'admin_init'                      ) );
        add_action(     'admin_footer',             array( $this, 'admin_footer'                    ), 20);

        add_filter(     'body_class',               array( $this, 'wpsocialite_body_class'          ) );
        add_filter(     'the_content',              array( $this, 'wpsocialite_filter_content'      ) );
        add_filter(     'mce_external_plugins',     array( $this, 'wpsocialite_shortcode_plugin'    ) );
        add_filter(     'mce_buttons',              array( $this, 'wpsocialite_shortcode_button'    ) );
        add_filter(     'plugin_action_links',      array( $this, 'wpsocialite_settings_link'       ), 10, 2 );
        add_shortcode(  'wpsocialite',              array( $this, 'wpsocialite_shortcode'           ) );

        if( get_option( 'wpsocialite_excerpt' ) == 1 ){
            add_filter( 'the_excerpt',              array( $this, 'wpsocialite_filter_content'      ) );
        }

    } // __construct
```

How to reference it to remove it?

Answer (score 3):

Because I found this through Google, and none of the answers worked:

```
function remove_silly_object_filter($filter_name, $class_name, $function_name){
  global $wp_filter;
  foreach($wp_filter[ $filter_name ]->callbacks as $priority => $pri_data){
    foreach ($pri_data as $cb => $cb_data){
      if (is_array($cb_data['function']) && get_class($cb_data['function'][0]) == $class_name && $cb_data['function'][1] == $function_name){
        $object = $cb_data['function'][0];
        $priority_to_remove = $priority;
        $function = $cb_data['function'][1];
        break;
      }
    }
    if (isset($object)) break;
  }
  remove_filter($filter_name,  array($object, $function), $priority_to_remove);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, it worked for me:

```
if ( class_exists( 'YITH_WC_Save_For_Later_Premium' ) ) {
    $yith_wc_save_for_later_premium = YITH_WC_Save_For_Later_Premium::get_instance(); /* <-- this is the key */
    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', array( $yith_wc_save_for_later_premium, 'print_add_link_in_list'), 20 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a [mini plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and use like:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Remove other plugin filter */

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function() 
{
    add_action( 'template_redirect', function() 
    {
        if( is_page_template( 'thank-you.php' ) )
            remove_filter( 'the_content', array( wpsocialite::$instance, 'wpsocialite_filter_content' ) );
    });
});
```

I used the following class as simulation of the other plugin:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Original plugin */

class wpsocialite {
    public static $instance;
    private $options;
    public function WPSocialite() {
        $this->__construct();
    }
    function __construct() {
        self::$instance = $this;
        add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'wpsocialite_filter_content' ) );
    } 
    function wpsocialite_filter_content( $content ) {
        return 'no content';
    }
}
new wpsocialite();
```

<sub>Reference: [remove_action or remove_filter with external classes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36013/remove-action-or-remove-filter-with-external-classes)</sub>

Comment: I have tried that before, I edited the question to hopefully explain where my headache is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for trying b. It throw the wordpress blank white page at me.

Comment: [De-anonymize](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19658445/2) PHP5.3+ functions, you gotta be running 5.2 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I came across it on Google, so in case others do as well...

I believe the static `$instance` variable (which is assigned `$self`) is the key and so it should be as simple as:

```
<?php if(is_page_template(thank-you.php)){
   remove_filter('the_content', array( wpsocialite::$instance, 'wpsocialite_filter_content' ));
}
```